# Change tab size of "cat" command

Tags: cat, indentation

When I am in `vim` I can change the tab size with the following command:

```
:set ts=4
```

Is it possible to set tab size for `cat` command output too?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The first command here *emulates* the formatting you see in `vim`.  It intelligently expands tabs to the equivalent number of spaces, based on a tab-STOP (ts) setting of every 4 columns.

```
printf "ab\tcd\tde\n" |expand -t4
```

Output

```
ab  cd  de
```

To keep the *tabs* as *tabs* and have the tab **STOP** positions set to every 4th column, then you must change the way the environment works with a tab-char (just as vim does with the `:set ts=4` command)

For example, in the terminal, you can set the tab **STOP** to 4 with this command;

```
tabs 4; printf "ab\tcd\tde\n"
```

Output

```
ab  cd  de
```

Comment: good to know (1). `expand` (from coreutils package) and `tabs` (from ncurses package) command, (2). and the meaning of ts is [**T**]ab [**S**]top

Answer (score 20):

Just use the following code:

```
tabs -n
```

Where n is the number of spaces you want tabs to correspond too.
In order to not having to do this every time you start the shell, just edit your `.bash_profile` in `~/` and add the above line to the end of the file.

For further info about the tabs command, refer to:

```
man tabs
```

Comment: Just beware that permanently changing your default tabs width might screw up other commands (for example `ls` out put may look not properly aligned).

Comment: Aliasing `ls` to `ls -T 0` helps with the `ls` output

Answer (score 12):

There's no notion of tabs or tab stops in `cat`; the program just funnels the inputs to the output and treats tabs like any other character.  If the output device happens to be a terminal, tabs will be handled according to whatever behavior the terminal is configured to provide.

Systems implementing POSIX.1 have a command called `tabs(1)` that will adjust the terminal's concept of how tabs should be displayed.  Depending on a particular tab layout is not considered a good idea, as someone may send your file to some other device such as a printer that won't do what you intended.

When you adjust `ts` in `vim` (or plain `vi`), all you're doing is adjusting how the editor interprets tab characters when displayed.  It has no bearing on what ends up in the file.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. How is the printer configured to treat tabs?

Comment: Most printers treat them the same way as most terminals do by default:  the left margin and every eight characters afterward.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the above answers and examples, it would seem that the actual command the OP wanted is...

`cat somefile | expand -t4`

This works for me on Red Hat 6.4.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the already given answers, `expand` can also take a list of tab stop positions. This is useful if the content lengths of the varlious columns varies a lot.

I came over this requirement today when I wanted to make the output of `openssl ciphers` more readable:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH'|tr -s ' ' '\t'|expand -t31,41,57,70,90
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384    TLSv1.2   Kx=ECDH         Au=RSA       Enc=AESGCM(256)     Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384  TLSv1.2   Kx=ECDH         Au=ECDSA     Enc=AESGCM(256)     Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384        TLSv1.2   Kx=ECDH         Au=RSA       Enc=AES(256)        Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384      TLSv1.2   Kx=ECDH         Au=ECDSA     Enc=AES(256)        Mac=SHA384
...
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA          SSLv3     Kx=ECDH/ECDSA   Au=ECDH      Enc=AES(128)        Mac=SHA1
AES128-GCM-SHA256              TLSv1.2   Kx=RSA          Au=RSA       Enc=AESGCM(128)     Mac=AEAD
AES128-SHA256                  TLSv1.2   Kx=RSA          Au=RSA       Enc=AES(128)        Mac=SHA256
AES128-SHA                     SSLv3     Kx=RSA          Au=RSA       Enc=AES(128)        Mac=SHA1

CAMELLIA128-SHA                SSLv3     Kx=RSA          Au=RSA       Enc=Camellia(128)   Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA             SSLv3     Kx=PSK          Au=PSK       Enc=AES(128)        Mac=SHA1
```

Using only `expand -t31` would blow up the width of the output from around 100 characters to more than 160 characters.

Comment: An easier way to do that is to use `column`: `openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH' | column -t`

Answer (score 2):

**For X terminal emulators (eg. `$TERM` is `xterm`, `st`, etc.):**

```
$ tabs -N
```

**For virtual consoles (no X Server, only text console where `$TERM` is `linux`, etc.):**

```
$ setterm --tegtabs N
```

Where `N` is an integer number of spaces to be used for TAB.

**Sed way insead of `tr` which translates `SET1` to `SET2` of characters in `1:1` 'proportions':**

```
$ sed 's/\t/    /g' FILENAME
           ^^^^^
        spaces here
```

Answer (score 0):

Many terminals support setting variable tab stops.  Those that are vt100, linux and or support the EMCA-48 standard do,
most terms on linux support setting tab size: xterm and family (uxterm, urxvt) xfce4-terminal, luit, Terminal, SecureTTY, among others.

So wrote a script a few years back to set my tabs at login to every 2 spaces -- used to use 4, then 3 for a short bit, and now at 2....

So now, if I 'cat' a file, tabs in the file will expand to my terminal's setting.

If I got through vim or more, they do their own tab expansion, but alot of utils use tabs.

Will include the script here for reference, and or personal use:

```
#!/bin/bash  -u
#console_codes(4) man page... vt100/2 et && EMCA-48 standard
# (c) la walsh (2013) -- free to use and modify for personal use.
#                     -- optionally licenced under Gnu v3 license.

# v0.0.3    - try to reduce tabcols to minimal set to reproduce.
# v0.0.2    - set tabs for full terminal width (try to get term width)

shopt -s expand_aliases extglob
alias my=declare        
alias int='my -i'       array='my -a' intArray='my -ia'   string=my

my _Pt=$(type -t P)
[[ $_Pt && $_Pt == function ]] && unset -f P
alias P=printf
unset _Pt

P -v clrallts  "\x1b[3g"    #Clear All TabStops
P -v hts       "\033H"      #Horizontal TabStop
P -v cpr       "\x1b[6n"    #Current Position Report


getcols() {                 # try to read terminal width
  local sttyout="$(stty size </dev/tty)"
  int default_cols=80
  if [[ -n ${COLUMNS:-""} && $COLUMNS =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then 
    default_cols=$COLUMNS; fi
  [[ -z ${sttyout:-""} ]] && { echo $default_cols; return 0; } 
  int cols="${sttyout#*\ }"
  echo -n $[cols<2?default_cols:cols]
  return 0
}

getpos () {
  string ans    wanted=${1:-xy}
  int attempt=0 max_attempt=1   # in case of rare failure case
                                # use 'attempt' value as additional
                                # time to wait for response
  while : ; do
    ( ( P "\x1b[6n" >/dev/tty) & 2>/dev/null )  
    read  -sd R -r -t $[2 + attempt] ans </dev/tty; 
    ans=${ans:2}; 
    int x=0-1 y=0-1
    if ! x="${ans#*;}" y="${ans%;*}" 2>/dev/null  || 
      ((x==-1||y==-1)); then
      ((attempt+=1 < max_attempt)) && continue
    fi
  break; done
  string out=""
  [[ $wanted =~ x ]] && out="$x"
  [[ $wanted =~ y ]] && out="${out:+$x }$y"
  [[ $out ]] && echo -n "$out"
}

declare -ia tabs


get_tabs () {
  P "\r"
  tabs=()
  int pos=0 oldpos=0-1
  while ((oldpos!=pos));do
    ((pos)) && tabs+=($pos)
    oldpos=pos
    P "\t"
    pos=$(getpos x)
  done
  P "\r"
  return 0
}

# Note: this func uses ability to _read_ tabstops as _proxy_ for setting them
# (i.e. it makes no sense to be able to read them if you can't set them)

test_tabset_ability () {
  string prompt="tty_tab:"
  int newcol=${#prompt}+1
  P "\r$prompt"
  int mycol=$(getpos x)
  ((mycol && mycol==newcol)) && return 0    ## return OK

  { P " Term tabset ability not detected mycol=${mycol:-''},"
    P " promptlen=$newcol)\n"; } >&2
  exit -1 
}

do_help_n_display_curtabs () {
  P " <n>   - set tab stop to N\r"
  intArray diffs;
  int last=1  cur i
  string eol=""
  get_tabs && {
    for ((i=0; i<${#tabs[@]}; ++i)); do
      cur=${tabs[i]}
      diffs[i]=cur-last
      last=cur
    done
    intArray reverse_tabs_set=()
    int prevtab=0-1
    for ((i=${#diffs[@]}-2; i>0; --i)); do
      int thistab=${diffs[i]}
      if ((thistab!= prevtab)) ;then 
        reverse_tabs_set+=($thistab)
        prevtab=thistab
      fi
    done
    P "current value: tty_tab "
      for ((i=${#reverse_tabs_set[@]}-1; i>=0; --i)); do
        P "%d " "${reverse_tabs_set[i]}"; done
    P "\r";
  }
  get_tabs  && {
    P "(from 1, tabs skip to column: "
    P "%s " "${tabs[@]}"
    P "\r\n"
  }
}

set_tabs () {
  int max_col=${1:=0-80}
  int tabstop=${2:-?"need a param for tabstop"}
  int tab=$tabstop        pos=0
  string str=""
  P $clrallts               ## reset old tabs
  while ((++pos<cols)) ;do  ## move across screen setting tabs
    str+=" "
    ((pos%tab)) || str+="$hts"
  done
  P "\r$str\r"
}


int cols=$(getcols)

test_tabset_ability         ## exits if no ability


if (($#==0)) ; then
  do_help_n_display_curtabs
  exit 1
else
  set_tabs "$cols" "$@"
fi

# vim: ts=2 sw=2
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score -2):

According to the manpage, cat can not do it on its own. But you can e.g. run the output from cat through `tr` filter to replace the tabs with any number of spaces you wish:

```
cat somefile | tr '\t' '  '
```

will replace the tab character with two spaces.

Update: as pointed out in the comments to this post, this actually **does not** work. Nevertheless, I'm keeping the answer as an example of how **not** to do it.

Comment: It's actually replacing `'\t'` with only one space, no matter how many spaces are in between the second pair of quotes `'      '`

Comment: `tr` doesn't work that way..  each **byte** of arg 1 is substituted by each corresponding **byte** of arg 2..... Therefore `printf '\t' |tr '\t' 'ळ'`  prints out a single byte whose hex value is `\xE0` .. which is the first byte of the three UTF-8 encoded bytes which make up the character `ळ` (whose Unicode CodePoint value is U+0933)

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks for catching my silly mistake!