# How to set default tabs only for cat?

Tags: command-line, cat, tabulation

I prefer to set `tabs 4` however this may have some side effects, such as [for example `ls` out put may look not properly aligned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111838/9760). **How might I configure the terminal / cat to use four spaces for tabs for cat only?**

Should I just alias / wrap `cat` to something that sets `tabs 4`, runs `/bin/cat`, then sets it back? My thinking is that this route is less preferable since in fact I would like this behaviour for `less`, `diff`, and other utilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The curses program [tabs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tabs) will allow you to change what the terminal believes to be the width of a `^I`. This would make a simple script

```
tabs -4
cat "$@"
tabs -8
```

However, the processing of <kbd>tab</kbd> characters on terminals is notoriously wonky and I'm of the impression that you should **never** mess with them. I suggest using [expand](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expand) as in:

```
expand -4 "$@"
```

which is actually closer to what you intend.

---

**added in reply to comment**:

Far too many scripts count on `cat` meaning `/bin/cat` which explicitly does not change tabs. I'm not sure if you mean to replace or supersede /bin/cat, but you shouldn't. Better would be:

```
alias tcat='expand -4'
```

or

```
function tcat() {
    expand -4 "$@"
}
```

or similar.